# I don't know why this is happening but my css will only apply to one of the pages I created in html

Tags: html, css

The css will only apply to one of the pages I created using html code. I checked the code and everything seems to be correct. All of the files I'm using are located on my laptop in the same website folder.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Mamma Mia Trattoria</title>
        <link rel="styelsheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="Menu" type="html" href="Menu.html">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="index.html"> Home </a>
            <a href="Menu.html"> Menu </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="header">
            <h1> Mamma Mia Trattoria </h1>
        </div>

        <p>
            <h2>Welcome to Mamma Mia Trattoria</h2>
<h2>Indulge in the Authentic Tastes of Italy</h2>
<br>

At Mamma Mia Trattoria, we invite you on a culinary journey through the heart of Italy, where the flavors are rich, 
the ingredients are fresh, and the tradition of good food is celebrated every day. Nestled in the heart of Little Italy, New York, 
our restaurant is a labor of love, a place where passion and culinary expertise come together to create an unforgettable 
dining experience.
<br>

<b> Our Story</b>
<br>
Mamma Mia Trattoria is more than just a restaurant; it's a celebration of Italian heritage and the art of gastronomy.
Our story began generations ago when Nonna shared her treasured family recipes, and now, we proudly bring those cherished traditions 
to your table. We believe in the power of simple, delicious food that warms the heart and brings people together.
<br>

<b>Our Menu</b>
<br>
Explore our menu and savor the authentic tastes of Italy. From classic pasta dishes that transport you to the streets of Rome, 
to hand-tossed pizzas that pay homage to Naples, every bite is a tribute to the culinary excellence of Italy. 
Our ingredients are carefully selected, our recipes are time-tested, and our chefs are passionate about creating memorable 
dining experiences.
<br>

<b>Ambiance</b>
<br>
Step into Mamma Mia Trattoria, and you'll be embraced by the cozy ambiance that evokes the warmth of an Italian home. 
The rustic decor, dimly lit chandeliers, and the aroma of freshly baked bread will transport you to the heart of Italy. 
Whether it's a romantic dinner for two or a festive gathering with friends and family, our restaurant is the perfect setting 
for every occasion.
<br>

<b>Join Us</b>
<br>
We invite you to join us on a gastronomic adventure. Whether you're a fan of classic Italian dishes or looking to explore new flavors,
 Mamma Mia Trattoria has something for everyone. Our commitment to quality, hospitality, and the joy of sharing exceptional food with 
 our guests is what sets us apart.
<br>

Reserve a table, order online, or simply drop by to experience the essence of Italy at Mamma Mia Trattoria. Buon appetito!
        </p>

<footer>
    <p>
        Created by Olivia Slusser
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Penn State University
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        IST 250
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Contact: oms5253@psu.edu
    </p>
</footer>

    </body>
</html>


html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

.topnav{
    background-color: burlywood;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.topnav a{
    float:left;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(243,170,110);
    color:black;
}

.topnav a:active{
    background-color: rgb(243,170,110);
    color:white;
}

.header{
    background-image:url(i-migliori-ristoranti-di-firenze-cover.jpg);
    background-position: 50%;
    min-height:35%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(227, 227, 227, 0.2);
    
}

body{
    
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    
}

h1{
    font-size: 56px;
    font: url(Great_Vibes/OFL.txt);
    color:black;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;

}


h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    color:black;
}

.column{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:rgb(203, 170, 130);
    text-align: center;
    padding:0%;
}
h3{
    font-size:30px;
    color:black;
}

.container2{
    padding:15px;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

h4{
    font-size:26px;
    color:black;
}

p{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:40px;
}


p3{
    font-size:24px;
}

footer{
    background-color:burlywood;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%
    
}
```

I tried looking up answers and asking reddit but the only thing I was told to do was to clear the cache. My code is saved so there isn't any issues with that and I copy and pasted the code from the index.html to the menu.html so I don't understand what could be wrong.

Comment: I see a typo. On line 5.  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` not `<link rel="styelsheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Comment: You didn't make it clear if you are trying to use same css on menu.html, if so, what css? The inline, or imported?

Answer (score 0):

was able to reproduce it. i think it's just a typo:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
```